# Meaning of javascript text between two slashes

Tags: javascript

On Dreamweaver if I write on a Javascript document some text between two slashes like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /text/
</script>
```

it becomes green.

What it the meaning of this text?
This is not a comment, neither "HTML text".

Thank you

Comment: Mozilla Regular Expression object documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Answer (score 9):

It is the regular expression literal.

From [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp):

```
var patt=new RegExp(pattern,modifiers);

or more simply:

var patt=/pattern/modifiers;
```

And from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):

```
RegExp(pattern [, flags])

/pattern/flags
```

Comment: Thank you. If always used the new RegExp.
I thought that in JS was like PHP, where the Regular expression is between quotes

Comment: What is the significance of it just sitting there with no assignment?  What purpose could it have?

Comment: Write it so: "/something/" and use it in a function

Comment: Just as a side note, w3schools is not the best reference out there: http://w3fools.com/ instead use https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript

Answer (score 2):

[It's a RegExp literal.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) I recommend doing your own research on the topic. I could write an introduction to finite automata and regular languages, but you'd always be able to find a better introduction with a little searching.

Answer (score -1):

You can use regular expression literals like this:

```
var pattern = /([0-9]+)/;
if(pattern.test(someString)) {
    // ...
} else {
    // ...
}
```

See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions